# How do i get the SID-History value using c# from active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, sid

I have a problem i've been struggling with.
I am trying to get the sidhistory property from an AD searchresult.
Is there anyone that can shed some light, or point me in the right direction on how to get the sidhistory property value?

This is an example of what i do ....i iterate through the properties, but there is not sidhistory property when i debug the code.

```
using (DirectoryEntry directoryEntryUser = new DirectoryEntry(searchResult.Path))
{
    foreach (string propertyName in directoryEntryUser.Properties.PropertyNames)
    {
            PropertyValueCollection propertyValues = 
            directoryEntryUser.Properties[propertyName];
            // And the rest of the code goes here
            // to get the values.
            // Sid-History or any variation never displays here 
            // as a property name
            // however objectsid does display
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all properties are loaded by default, you should use the `PropertiesToLoad` property of the DirectoryEntry, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload.aspx)